# Is there a way to direct query Salesforce Objects to Power Query/Power BI without having to extract the object

Tags: powerbi, salesforce, powerquery, salesforce-einstein

My data lives in Salesforce objects and I am trying to connect Power Query to Salesforce Objects. The limitation here is that I have to extract the whole object and then filter the required fields. Is there an option to direct query salesforce object without having to extract the object.

Answer (score 0):

No, for SalesForce objects or reports you can't use direct query.
The full list of data sources you can or can't use direct query against, see the page at the MS Docs website:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible if you use a third-party connector where you can query fields such as:

- Account
- Lead
- Contact
- Task
- Opportunity
- Campaign

these should be the fields that are possible to request from salesforce REST API.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference.htm